# Drop-down menu showing contents of sub menu, on hover

Tags: html, css, css-position, navigationbar

I've been trying to figure out how to make a Navbar with a drop down menu.  I feel like I'm super close, but for some reason when I hover over my main list element, it shows the entire contents of the submenus as well.

This is the point I keep getting stuck, I've tried adding in, switching around li, and ul in my CSS, but its just not working.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, san-serif;
}

body {
  background-color: pink;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  padding-top: .4em;
  background-color: coral;
  height: 2em;
  width: 100%;
}

nav {
  background: red;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  width: 100%;
}

nav>ul>li {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: yellow;
  background-color: purple;
  width: 31%;
  height: auto;
}

nav>ul>li>ul {
  background-color: blue;
  list-style: none;
  position: absolute;
  /*display: none;*/
  width: 100%;
}

nav>ul>li:hover ul li {
  display: block;
}

nav>ul>li>ul>li>ul {
  list-style: none;
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  width: 40%;
  display: none;
}

nav>ul>li>ul>li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Web Page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:\Users\geek\Desktop\positions\styles.css">
</head>
<header>
  <H1>My Web Page</H1>
</header>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>Music
          <ul>
            <li>Song 1
              <ul>
                <li>Thing 1
                </li>
                <li>Thing 2
                </li>
                <li>Thing 3
                </li>
                <li>Thing 4
                </li>
                <li>Thing 5
                </li>
                <li>Thing 6
                </li>

              </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Song 2</li>
            <li>Song 3</li>
            <li>Song 4</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

The first drop-down items should be centered with the Navbar element (Music).
Every sub-menu after that should appear top 0px; left 100%, of the list item (Song 1 in this case).  You can see the expected results in my CSS.

Comment: One thing, it seems strange to be using so many `>` CSS selectors all over the place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
color: white;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, san-serif;
}

body {
background-color: pink;
}

h1 {
text-align: center;
margin: auto;
padding-top: .4em;
background-color: coral;
height:2em;
width: 100%;
} 

nav {
background: red;
margin: auto;
padding:10px;
line-height: 1.6em;
width: 100%;
}

nav > ul >li {
position: relative;
text-align: center;
color: yellow;
background-color: purple;
width: 31%;
height: auto;
}  

/* i added only following codes */

nav ul li ul li ul {
  display:none;
}

nav ul li ul li:hover ul {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Web Page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
href="C:\Users\geek\Desktop\positions\styles.css">

</head>
<header>
<H1>My Web Page</H1>
</header>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li>Music
                <ul>
                    <li>Song 1
                        <ul>
                            <li>Thing 
1</li>
                            <li>Thing 
2</li>
                            <li>Thing 
3</li>
                            <li>Thing 
4</li>
                            <li>Thing 
5</li>
                            <li>Thing 
6</li>

                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>Song 2</li>
                    <li>Song 3</li>
                    <li>Song 4</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Still doesn't work.  I think I'm misusing selectors.

Comment: When I copy and paste your CSS, it works, but I have to delete my whole CSS otherwise, no effect.  Also, things aren't positioned correctly anymore.  I gain the functionality without the design.

Answer (score 1):

A very similar example of what you are trying to achieve, in this case is on click but you can get the idea on how to do it on `:hover`

https://codepen.io/Angel-SG/pen/JwXRZo